# Swift: dynamically creating and assigning delegates

Tags: swift, delegates, mkmapview, weak-references, strong-references

MKMapView's delegate property is defined as so in swift:

```
@IBOutlet weak open var delegate: MKMapViewDelegate?.
```

If I had to dynamically create map views for each item in an array whose length/count is unknown beforehand, how I dynamically assign a unique delegate instance to each one of the maps without keeping a class variable for each delegate (since we don't know the count of items in the array). Is there something similar to Obj-C's `__Strong` ?

**Update**:
I could have a class array to which I add each delegate, but still, are there any other approaches, which are more inline for example by using __Strong, if there is such a thing in Swift

Comment: “Other answers here on stack suggest keeping a class variable as the strong reference for the delegate. Thats the solution I want to avoid...” - You might want to avoid that, but that’s the right answer. Because the map view only keeps a `weak` reference to its `delegate`, if you don’t want it deallocated, you’re going to have to establish your own strong reference to that object somewhere. And, no, using a local variable obviously isn’t going to work (even if it does happen to silence the warning).

Comment: @rob, how about the example situation. How would you work with that. You can't keep a class delegate variable in that case.

Comment: Like you said in your update, you can have an array of those delegate objects.

Comment: @Rob, right right. I see. Thought I'ld check first. Hopefully in the future we can get something similar to __Strong for inline weak delegate retention.

Comment: No there isn’t. Sorry. We really should just delete/close this question...

Comment: @Rob too early to call it mate. There may be other ways to skin the cat that you are not aware of. Yes, there isn't a strong, that's why I say hopefully in the future.

Comment: And closing it doesn't make sense, there is an answer, one of which is the solution I mentioned in my update, the use of an array. My question is based on the condition of an undetermined number multiple  delegates (that's the question). Add a link to such an existing question and answer and I will delete this.

Comment: No. The answer is just “keep your own strong reference to the object”. Whether you have a collection of them or just one, it’s just a strong reference. This has been asked and answered many times.

Comment: @Rob But is there a question similar or identical to mine? Just because the answer has been given in a different but similar post doesn't mean that this question is invalid. It's valid in its own right.

Comment: My question is not on keeping the strong reference, I already know that. My question is on how to handle multiple number (unknown) of delegates in swift. Is there such a question? Please add link. Perhaps I should rephrase my title to make it apparent

Comment: @Rob Done. Updated question to be explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how I dynamically assign a unique delegate instance to each one of the maps without keeping a class variable for each delegate

There's no need for a unique delegate object for each map view. Delegate methods typically get a reference to the delegator as their first parameter, so the delegate can easily tell which map view is sending the message.

Comment: Good point. What if the delegate had to keep certain information for the map it handles. For example, keeping variable that holds the date time the user last scrolled it. In that case a unique delegate per map is required... Good point though. I'm probably looking way too much into it.

Comment: Regarding the situation I just mentioned, that property could be added onto a map subclass, and use that property within that one delegate. So back to your point. Absolutely right.

Comment: That, or the delegate could store the information in a dictionary where the map view is the key and the date of last scroll is the value.